# Installing IIS on windows 2003 without the windows CD

Tags: installation, windows-server-2003

Ihave a server that I need to install IIS on - however I don't have the windows 2003 CD available.  It prompts me to insert the CD labeled "Service Pack 2 CD-ROM" - I've downloaded the service pack and it's not able to find the file it needs in there.  How can I get IIS to install w/o the windows CD?

Answer (score 4):

Do you have an I386 folder on the machine? If so you should be able to install it from there.

Answer (score 3):

It will prompt you for SP2 files first -- these are in your Windows\ServicePackFiles\i386.  Then it will prompt you for Windows Server 2003 RTM files -- these are on the CD.  You can use any CD -- it does not have to be the same key as the one you've used to install with.

Answer (score 2):

You also can take this from another server in your network "\server\C$" and then select the i386 folder.